# Cursor не меняет значение pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py, pymysql

Возможно я вообще не понимаю как работает cursor при работе с бд, но проблема такая. Я делаю discord бота и когда пользователь вводит команду он должен проверять есть ли у него на это права, делая запрос с бд. Для этого я написал функцию `has_permissions()`:

```
def has_permissions(ctx):
    def check_users():
        print("check_users")
        author_id = ctx.author.id
        allowed_users = permissions['user_ids']
        for i in range(len(allowed_users)):
            if allowed_users[i] == author_id:
                return True
        else:
            return False
    def check_roles():
        print("check_roles")
        author_roles = ctx.author.roles
        allowed_roles = permissions['user_roles']
        for i in range(len(author_roles)):
            for ii in range(len(allowed_roles)):
                if allowed_roles[ii] == author_roles[i].id:
                    return True
        else:
            return False

    row = fetchone(f"SELECT `permissions` FROM `guilds_data` WHERE `guild_id` = {str(ctx.message.guild.id)}")['permissions']
    permissions = json.loads(row)[ctx.command.name]

    if permissions['only_owner']:
        if ctx.author.id == ctx.message.guild.owner_id:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif permissions['only_admins']:
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif check_users() or check_roles():
        return True
    else:
        raise commands.MissingPermissions(permissions)
```

Запрос в бд делается через функцию `fetchone()`:

```
def fetchone(query):
    try:
        with connect.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            return cursor.fetchall()[0]
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда я меняю значения в бд через PhpMyAdmin при запущенном боте, то курсор постоянно содержит только те значения, которые были при первом вызове. В моем понимание он должен каждый раз брать актуальные данные. Как это сделать и что у меня не так?

Вот весь код:

```
import discord
import json
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import File

TOKEN = '(тут типо токен)'
connect = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'FatherBot', password = 'AjeXXp7jvdRX8Bnw', db = 'fatherbot', 
    charset = 'utf8mb4', cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
#ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ К БД
def fetchone(query):
    try:
        with connect.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            return cursor.fetchall()[0]
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()

#ВСПОМОГАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ФУНКЦИИ
async def get_prefix(bot, message):
    row = fetchone(f"SELECT `settings` FROM `guilds_data` WHERE `guild_id` = {str(message.guild.id)}")['settings']
    return json.loads(row)['prefix']
bot = Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)

def has_permissions(ctx):
    def check_users():
        print("check_users")
        author_id = ctx.author.id
        allowed_users = permissions['user_ids']
        for i in range(len(allowed_users)):
            if allowed_users[i] == author_id:
                return True
        else:
            return False
    def check_roles():
        print("check_roles")
        author_roles = ctx.author.roles
        allowed_roles = permissions['user_roles']
        for i in range(len(author_roles)):
            for ii in range(len(allowed_roles)):
                if allowed_roles[ii] == author_roles[i].id:
                    return True
        else:
            return False

    row = fetchone(f"SELECT `permissions` FROM `guilds_data` WHERE `guild_id` = {str(ctx.message.guild.id)}")['permissions']
    permissions = json.loads(row)[ctx.command.name]

    if permissions['only_owner']:
        if ctx.author.id == ctx.message.guild.owner_id:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif permissions['only_admins']:
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif check_users() or check_roles():
        return True
    else:
        raise commands.MissingPermissions(permissions)

#СОБЫТИЯ
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("FatherBot connected and ready")

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('У вас недостаточно прав для выполнения данной команды!')

#КОМАНДЫ
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, mention, reason=None):
    if has_permissions(ctx):
        pass

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Вы проверяете какие-то специальные права доступа? Если нет то в [докумендации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permiss#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) есть функция которая проверяет если ли у роли пользователя который использует эту команду, например права администратора. Также прочетайте вот эту [документацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permiss#checks)про проверки в discord.py

Comment: да я знаю о данной возможности, но здесь нужна именно своя реализация для дальнейшей настройки через сайт. Проблема то не в этом. Проблема в связи с бд. Перечитайте еще раз вопрос